# Como selecionar em uma tabela como se fosse dois registros

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Na tabela **pessoa** tem as seguintes informações

```
ID  |  NOME  |  É_ALUNO  |  É_RESPONSAVEL
1   |  ALUNO |  TRUE     |  FALSE
2   |  RESPON|  FALSE    |  TRUE
```

Há outra tabela com o nome **responsavel_aluno**, nesta tabela tem as seguintes informações;

```
ID   |   ALUNO   |   RESPONSAVEL
1    |   1       |   2
```

Gostaria dar um select como abaixo:

```
NOME   |  ALUNO
RESPON |  ALUNO
```

Qual a melhor forma de dar este select?

Comment: Se entendi direito: Seria algo como 
SELECT tmain.nome as nome_aluno, taux.nome as nome_responsavel
FROM pessoa as tmain 
INNER JOIN responsavel_aluno as tresponsavel ON tresponsavel.id = tmain.id AND tmain.É_aluno is true 
INNER JOIN pessoa as taux ON taux.id = tresponsavel.responsavel
Espero ter ajudado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creio que esse select pode ajudar:

```
SELECT a.nome AS aluno_nome, r.nome AS responsavel_nome
FROM pessoa a, pessoa r, responsavel_aluno ra
WHERE r.e_responsavel = true AND a.e_aluno = true AND ra.aluno = a.id AND ra.responsavel= r.id
```

Answer (score 3):

Usando `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT p.nome AS aluno, r.nome AS responsavel
FROM pessoa p
INNER JOIN responsavel_aluno r ON p.id = r.responsavel
WHERE p.e_responsavel = true
```